# Convince referee "of" foul play

Tags: prepositional-phrases, complementation

According to dictionaries, the usage of "convince somebody of something" pattern seems to require that "something" to be a quality, not action.  Examples of this correct usage would be:

> 1. He convinced them of ***his innocence***.
> 2. He convinced them of ***the safety*** of the machine.

where, "innocence" and "safety" are qualities.

But then, there is this [sentence](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-srv/special/sports/world-cup-2014/dives/#dive/2014-06-26_Group-G_Portugal-vs-Ghana_Waris_Yellow_55):

> Whether it’s a dramatic fall, an open-mouth shriek or a prolonged roll on the ground, having the theatrical ability to *convince a referee of* ***an opponent’s foul play*** is part of an effective soccer strategy.

In "convince a referee of *an opponent’s foul play*", "foul play" is an action, not a quality.  Could the sentence be wrong?

Comment: The key is in your observation **seems** *to require* - apparently based on 2 data points.  In the world of English usage examples, I'd be skeptical of the validity of an hypothesis based on just two usage data points and so I would tend to question my hypothesis, and not the data, when confronted with new, non-conforming data.  I'd then attempt to gather more data, like from Google ngrams. I'd also be skeptical of any *rule* that limited what could follow what, semantically in English.

Comment: The wizard convinced me of his murderous deed. For example.

Answer (score 5):

*Foul play* is a noun, just like *innocence* and *safety*.  We use *convince them **of*** when talking about nouns:

> *convince them of their wrongdoing; convince them of the truth*

We use *convince them **to*** when talking about verbs and actions:

> *convince them to go outside; convince them to get up and dance*

Of course, other prepositions can be used as well:

> *convince them by appealing to their emotions; convince them against their better judgment*

Answer (score 3):

I am somewhat sympathetic to your observation; I myself would express this with a *that* clause rather than an *of* phrase:

> ... the theatrical ability to convince a referee that an opponent has committed foul play.

But I have no real objection to the original; and I think you are wrong in saying that one convinces someone of a “quality”. What you convince someone of is a ***fact***. The term *fact* need not be employed, but it is there: it is built in to the meaning of the word *convince*.

And a fact may be a fact either of essence (noun) or accident (adjective) or of act (verb): not least because nouns are readily adjectivized, adjectives verbalized, and verbs nominalized. (In fact, *fact* was originally a participle: its oldest meaning, which it still has that meaning in many contexts, was a *deed*, a ‘thing done’.)

> He convinced them of [the fact of] his innocence.
> He convinced them that he was innocent.
>
> He convinced them of [the fact of] the machine's safety.
> He convinced them that the machine was safe.
>
> He convinced the referee of [the fact of] his opponent's foul play.
> He convinced the referee that his opponent's act was foul play.